# Sharepoint 2019 search without Enterprise Search

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-2019

Our organization has Sharepoint 2019 Server (On-Premise) licenses (via some partner subscription) and have bought Standard CALs.

So now we must deploy Sharepoint Server 2019 that would be legal to work via Standard CALs, without enterprise services: Excel Services, BCS, e-Discovery etc, and Enterprise Search too.

Is it possible to create a fresh Sharepoint farm without Enterprise Search, but still be able to search content?

Sharepoint Foundation 2010, for instance, had its own Search, limited, but still functional.

Does 2019 still have some "Standard Search" and if yes, how do I deploy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Standard CAL supports these standard search features such as people and expertise search, visual previews, visual best bets.

Create a search service application and do a full crawl for the first use.

More information:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Remember to mark it as answer if it helps.